# Can't sent to Maildir : postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, maildir

I set up 
/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, example02.com, mail01.example.local, localhost.example.local, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox=Maildir/
```

and

/etc/init.d/postfix restart

but..
You have new mail in /var/mail/user

Why?
What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox), `mailbox_command` takes precedence over `home_mailbox`.  Either disable the former, or set up your `.procmailrc` to deliver to Maildir (by suffixing the mailboxes with a slash, if memory serves).

Comment: Thank you very much.
But... How to write .procmailrc?
Could you give me a sample code?

Comment: Just get rid of the procmail call.  If you don't know how to use it, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Michiel](https://serverfault.com/questions/36195/cant-sent-to-maildir-postfix/36197#36197).  I have the same setup, with procmail doing local delivery.  I have the following in both `/etc/procmailrc` and my local `.procmailrc` files:

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
```